# While debugging the function breakpoint is not hit

Tags: debugging, powerbuilder

I am using powerbuilder 11.2 and I have a pbl that creates a main screen.  The user enters an order number in the textbox and hit enter and it fills in data in the bottom of the screen.  I am trying to get debugging to hit a breakpoint in my function but it seems to ignore the breakpoint.  Is there a way to break into the function?  I have a variable I need to evaluate and I can't seem to get into the function while running. Here is the code:

```
 Decimal{2} ld_total_hrs,ld_load_hrs,ld_unload_hrs
long            ll_stops_rowcount, ll_row, ll_type, ll_ord_number, ll_rd_rowcount
datetime        ldt_1st_stop, ldt_last_stop, ldt_start_time, ldt_end_time, ldt_deliver_time
string      ls_dest_id, ls_type, ls_pay_id, ls_ref_number, ls_pay_leg_config
boolean     lb_first_drop = TRUE

ld_load_hrs = 0
ld_unload_hrs = 0
SetNull(ldt_deliver_time)
ll_stops_rowcount = dw_trip.RowCount()

If ll_stops_rowcount < 1 then Return 0

For ll_row = 1 to ll_stops_rowcount
    If ll_row = 1 then
        ldt_1st_stop = dw_trip.GetItemDateTime ( 1, "stops_stp_arrivaldate" )
    End if

    If dw_trip.GetItemString(ll_row,"stops_stp_type") = "PUP" then
        ldt_start_time = dw_trip.GetItemDateTime(ll_row,"stops_stp_arrivaldate")
        ldt_end_time = dw_trip.GetItemDateTime(ll_row,"stops_stp_departuredate")
        ld_load_hrs = ld_load_hrs + (f_datetimediff(ldt_start_time,ldt_end_time)/60)/60
    End if

    If dw_trip.GetItemString(ll_row,"stops_stp_type") = "DRP" then
        ldt_start_time = dw_trip.GetItemDateTime(ll_row,"stops_stp_arrivaldate")
        ldt_end_time = dw_trip.GetItemDateTime(ll_row,"stops_stp_departuredate")
        ld_unload_hrs = ld_unload_hrs + (f_datetimediff(ldt_start_time,ldt_end_time)/60)/60
        // get the first drops info for the report if paylegaslane is true else get last drop

        ls_pay_leg_config = is_PayLegConfig

        If is_CompanyOverride=true then
             ls_pay_leg_config = "ByLeg"
        End if 
        //TGRIFFIT - PayLegConfig = 'ByLeg' in TMW is equivalent to 'PayLegAsLane = 'Y' in FSS
        if  Upper(ls_pay_leg_config) = 'BYLEG' then
            If lb_first_drop Then    
                ldt_deliver_time = ldt_end_time
                ls_dest_id = dw_trip.GetItemString(ll_row,"stops_cmp_id")
                ls_ref_number = dw_trip.GetItemString(ll_row,"stops_stp_refnum")
                lb_first_drop = FALSE
            End if
        else
            ldt_deliver_time = ldt_end_time
            ls_dest_id = dw_trip.GetItemString(ll_row,"stops_cmp_id")
            ls_ref_number = dw_trip.GetItemString(ll_row,"stops_stp_refnum")
        end if

    End if

Next

ldt_last_stop = dw_trip.GetItemDateTime ( ll_stops_rowcount, "stops_stp_departuredate" )
ld_total_hrs = (f_datetimediff(ldt_1st_stop,ldt_last_stop)/60)/60
ll_ord_number = long(dw_triptab.GetItemString(1,"ord_number"))

//If g_messlevel% < 1 Then
if gnv_app.ii_MessLevel < 1 Then
    ids_revdist.Reset()
End if  

//Load the datastore that stores all the revenue distribution values 
ll_rd_rowcount = ids_revdist.RowCount()
ids_revdist.InsertRow(0)
ll_rd_rowcount ++

ids_revdist.SetItem(ll_rd_rowcount,"mov_number",i_movenum%)
ids_revdist.SetItem(ll_rd_rowcount,"lgh_number",dw_trip.GetItemNumber(1,"stops_lgh_number"))
ids_revdist.SetItem(ll_rd_rowcount,"total_hours",ld_total_hrs)
ids_revdist.SetItem(ll_rd_rowcount,"load_hours",ld_load_hrs)
ids_revdist.SetItem(ll_rd_rowcount,"unload_hours",ld_unload_hrs)
ids_revdist.SetItem(ll_rd_rowcount,"deliver_date",ldt_deliver_time)
ids_revdist.SetItem(ll_rd_rowcount,"dest_code",ls_dest_id)
ids_revdist.SetItem(ll_rd_rowcount,"ref_number",ls_ref_number)

Return ids_revdist.RowCount()
```

I need to evaluate this line specifically and I set a breakpoint at this line:

ls_pay_leg_config = "ByLeg"

as well as the following lines.  It does not break.  I am rusty at PowerBuilder and can figure this out.

Comment: When the debugger becomes erratic, you could always try to restart the IDE and perform a full rebuild. But you could simply not be in the case where your line cannot be reached due to the logic. Are you sure that the case will occur? If you know a line that should be concerned, you could put a BP on the line with the GetItemString() and fill a condition for the BP like `ll_row = 42` for the 42th line. Pu the BP then in the debugger view, show the BP properties by right-click then `breakpoints...`, put some code in the `condition` field. You can either fill the `occurrence` field

Comment: If your function isn't in the window where you're calling it and you've changed the function, you need to regenerate everything that references the function. If that doesn't work go with Seki's recommendation, which applies anytime PowerBuilder is acting weird.

Answer (score 0):

Put the breakpoint at the start of the loop.